# Voice recognition with android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice

Hey guys, I was wondering if it were possible to translate audio without having to call a recognizer intent (ie a dialog that says you are recording audio). I want to be able to recover the results of the voice recognition every 2 to 3 seconds or so and plan to use this with a bunch of listviews. Is this possible? If so any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am playing around with android.speech.SpeechRecognizer but so far, in my implementation of the RecognitionListener interface all I have been able to get from ddms is that there is a client side error. Nothing else seems to be called. Also, is it essential that I implement a RecognitionService? I know that the example in the API is just that. If so, how would I create and use this service? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just posted some working code skeleton stuff in another thread -

[Voice Recognition Commands Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348829/voice-recognition-commands-android/6351045#6351045)

The speech recognizer can be triggered every few seconds without UI. You might need to write your own code to decide when is good to record and when is not (you get an audio buffer you could peek through) - or your could do something in your own UI.

I think you could re-trigger it over and over again. Not sure it'd work perfectly but worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

Speech recognition does not work in the Emulator.  You need a device.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in Android < 2.1 and probably in 2.2

When I asked a Google support person, he said, "Maybe you can figure out what packets are being sent and then just make a direct web call"

Wow.

Comment: Wow -_-. But yes, I have been playing around with 2.2 sdk but I just can't seem to get anything to work (other than a client side error message in my Recognition interfaced class). I assumed that the SpeechRecognition class was different than the Recognition intent class in that you wouldn't have to use an intent to use the recognition service.

Comment: Actually, figured it out. Very simple with 2.2 actually. SpeechRecognizer is accessing the Recognition service for you, so there is no need to bind to a service or anything.